# provability and theorem

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms, provability

I am studying first order logic and I have a hard time understanding the link between provable formulas and theorem.
In the book by Shoenfield, the predicate $ Pr_{T}(a,b)$ of is defined as the set of (a,b) such that there exists formulas $A_{1},A_2,...,A_k$ which are a proof in T and $<Num(A_1),...,Num(A_k)>=b$ and a=$Num(A_k)$. This predicate is recursive and thus representable in the theory N by a formula $B^T$ with x,y distinct variables. Then we define $A^T$ as $\exists y B^T$.

So if I understood well, $T|-A^T_{x}[ \underline{Num(E)}] $ means that there exists a proof of E in T.
We also have 3 derivability conditions, one of which interests me here:

if $T|- D $ then $N|-A^T_{x}[ \underline{Num(D)}] $

My issue is that I don't see why this relation is not an equivalence. Because if $T|-A^T_{x}[ \underline{Num(D)}] $ then it means that $D$ is provable in T and thus that it is a theorem.

Can anyone help me with this matter ?

Thanks!

Comment: What page, please ?

Comment: Yes, they can be expressed with iff: $\vdash_T \varphi \text { 
 iff  } \vdash_T \text {Thm}_T(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$. See e.g Bernd Buldt, [The Scope of Gödel’s First Incompleteness Theorem (LogUni, 2014)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11787-014-0107-3)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. As for the page, I'm sorry I thought it was in this book but it is only in the notes of my teacher (which uses Shoenfield as the basis for its course). Now about your answer, if I am being correct $Thm_T(a)$ is equivalent to $ \exists x P(a,x) $, so it would mean that the relation that I was concern about is indeed an equivalence right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

The so-called arithmetization of syntax is relative to a theory $T$ with language $L$ [page 123].

The author defines a collection of numerical predicates and relations that mimic the properties of theory $T$: $\text {Term}, \text {Ax}, \text {For}$ and so on.

Specifically, predicate $\text {Pr}_t$ is a binary predicate holding of numbers $a$ and $b$ iff $b$ is the number corresponding to a proof [a *derivation* in $T$] ending with formula $A$ and $a$ is the number corresponding to $A$, i.e. $a= \ulcorner A \urcorner$.

Then the author defines anew unary predicate: $\text {Thm}_T(a) \leftrightarrow \exists x\text {Pr}_T(a,x)$, that means: there is a proof [in $T$] of formula $A$, i.e. $A$ is a theorem of theory $T$.

Now, to say that a numerical (unary) predicate $P$ is *representable* in theory $\mathsf N$ means that there is a formula $A_P$ of the theory such that:

> if $P(a)$ holds, then $\mathsf N \vdash A_P[k_a/x]$, where $k_a$ is the *numeral* corresponding to $a$, and

> if $P(a)$ does not hold, then $\mathsf N \vdash \lnot A_P[k_a/x]$.

Now we have the condition that $\text {Thm}(a)$ is representable in $\mathsf N$.

This means that:

> if $\text {Thm}(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$ holds, i.e. $\mathsf N \vdash \varphi$, then $\mathsf N \vdash A_T[k_a/x]$,

where $a= \ulcorner \varphi \urcorner$.

The condition: if $\mathsf N \vdash \varphi$, then $\mathsf N \vdash A_T[k_a/x]$, is the first derivability condition.

But we have to note that the second clause of *representability* is: if $P(a)$ does not hold, then $\mathsf N \vdash \lnot A_P[k_a/x]$.

When we apply it to $\text {Thm}$ we have: if $\mathsf N \nvdash \varphi$, then $\mathsf N \vdash \lnot A_T[k_a/x]$ that is stronger than:

> if $\mathsf N \nvdash \varphi$, then $\mathsf N \nvdash A_P[k_a/x]$.